# vba error : this key is already associated with an element of this collection

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

i am using two combo-box in my sheet and item list of second combo-box based on the value selected in  first combo-box  and i am using following code for that but it gives the error "this key is already associated with an element of this collection" on "oDictionary.Add cel.value, 0" line of code .

```
    Set secondItem = Sheet2.Range("b1:b30")
    Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Sheet3.ComboBox2.Clear
    With Sheet3.ComboBox2
    For Each cel In secondItem
    If ComboBox1.value = cel.Offset(, -1).value Then

        oDictionary.Add cel.value, 0
        ComboBox2.AddItem (cel.value)

    End If
Next cel
End With
```

what is the solution of this issue .....

thanks in advance ......

Comment: What's the point of the Dictionary here? If you're trying to create a unique list, you should only be adding them to the Dictionary, then adding all its Keys to the combobox at the end. You can either test for an existing key using the `.Exists` method of the Dictionary, or just use: `oDictionary(cel.value) = 0`

Comment: thanks @Rory for your response , is there any  other way than Dictionary to store unique list ...

Comment: Several, but what's wrong with a Dictionary? It would seem ideally suited for what you're doing.

Comment: Do you have duplicates in `B1:B30` where the corresponding value in column `A` is the same? Agree with @Rory that there is no need for the `Dictionary` in your code as it stands. You can add duplicate values to  from `cel.value` to `ComboBox2`. You better update the question with the purpose for the `Dictionary`.